# vb.net how to find a range of digits in string

Tags: vb.net

I would like to split a String by a range of digits (0 to 20) and the letters should be `.toLower`

How can I define the range in my code?

I have tried to do it like this:`("0","1","2","3")`

```
                    Dim Tolerancevalueofext As String = "JS12"
                    Dim removenumber As String = Tolerancevalueofext.Substring(0, Tolerancevalueofext.IndexOf("0","1","2","3")).ToLower
```

But that is definitely wrong.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: can you show the the desired output?

Comment: And input samples - both would be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your request i quite unclear but here is a way to:
1. extract only numbers from string (using [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)). 

2. extracting only letters from string that contains digits and converting them to small letters.

```
Private Sub Example()
    Dim Tolerancevalueofext As String = "JS12"

    ' only numbers, output: "12"
    Dim onlynumbers As String = extractNumberFromString(Tolerancevalueofext).ToString()
    ' only characters, output: "js"
    Dim onlycharacters As String = String.Empty
    For Each line As String In Tolerancevalueofext
        If Not (IsNumeric(line)) Then
            onlycharacters += line.ToLower()
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Public Shared Function extractNumberFromString(ByVal value As String) As Integer
    Dim returnVal As String = String.Empty
    Dim collection As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(value, "\d+")

    For Each m As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match In collection
        returnVal += m.ToString()
    Next

    Return Convert.ToInt32(returnVal)
End Function
```

> Output: 
>  onlynumbers = "12" 
>  onlycharacters = "js"